# Hosting a Routing based web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hosting, web-hosting

I am hosting a website (**A webform application**) but loading login page is showing this error: 
http://blog.milstein.me

> External component has thrown an exception. System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.b__1(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder) at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass32`2.b__30() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10(Object param0) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureFirstTimeDirectoryInit(VirtualPath virtualDir) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(String virtualPath) at SageFrame.Framework.PageBase.LoadControl(String UpdatePanelIDPrefix, Boolean IsPartialRendring, PlaceHolder ContainerControl, String ControlSrc, String PaneName, String strUserModuleID, String suffixClass, String HeaderText, Boolean IsUserAdmin, HtmlGenericControl divControl, HtmlGenericControl paneControl, Boolean IsEdit)

However, the home page and other routed pages are loading perfectly!
What is the main reason for this issue? How to fix it? The hosted .NET version is .NET 4.0.

Comment: it seems to work fine now?

Comment: @RobTillie can you explain what that error log actually mean?

Comment: It can't compile something it tries to load, from the looks of it a template control on your page. If it's working fine locally, it's probably due to some reference missing in the deployment, or the wrong .net configuration in IIS. But did you solve it as it is loading correctly now?

Comment: So what was the problem? Perhaps you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens due to the hosting Application pool caching mechanism. In Hosting c-panel, there is App Pool clearing option for each hosted websites. After clearing the cache, it loads the all new referenced dll properly.